# I cant get the resulation of BeautifulSoup commant

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spyder

I have started to using BeautifulSoup yet.I made a script like this:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parsePrice():    
    r=requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Mann%20Co.%20Supply%20Crate%20Key')
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")
    price=soup.find_all('span',{'class':'market_commodity_orders_header_promote'})[0].find('span').text
    return price

while True:
    print('the current price: '+str(parsePrice()))
```

When i hit the run button and it shows error as,

```
 runfile('C:/Users/tuck/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/tuck/.spyder-py3')
    Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\tuck\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 15, in <module>
    print('the current price: '+str(parsePrice()))

  File "C:\Users\tuck\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 11, in parsePrice
    price=soup.find_all('span',{'class':'market_commodity_orders_header_promote'})[0].find('span').text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Image for desired output:

[image: Here is what im trying to get with BeautifulSoup.]

Comment: If you take a look at the source code of that page you will find that the element you are looking for is not on the page... It is probably dynamically updated by JavaScript, making it way harder to parse with something like bs4.

Comment: Oh, this is true. Thank you for comment but is there any way to make getting prices live?

Comment: One option would be to use Selenium instead to scrape the values out of the website via a browser. This way the javascript would be executed and the value you are looking for will be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes contents are loaded dynamically so what can you do first go to
   chrome developer and find Network tab and go to xhr tab
2. Then refresh your site now you can see in name tab links are present
   now click on that links and find your data
3. So it contains json data now you can copy the link address of link
   which is contain right information also i have added image for better understanding

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=IN&language=english&currency=1&item_nameid=1&two_factor=0') 
main_data=r.json()
html=main_data['sell_order_summary']

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
soup.text
```

Output:

```
'10079 for sale starting at $2.47'
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: This is working without any problem. Thank you so much for helping :)